# Pass api property to not connected lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, properties

Those lwc are on one screen flow, but its only connection between them.
I need to pass api property from one lwc to another, but they must be separate.  So my '@api selectedProjectId' value must be available in 2 separate lwc. Maybe its possible with events?
Help me, please.
Code is just for example.

```
    <template>
    <lightning-card title="Create and View Account Record">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
        
            <lightning-record-form object-api-name="Account" record-id={strRecordId}
            columns="2" mode="edit" fields={arrayFields}></lightning-record-form>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

```
    import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ShowAccount extends LightningElement {
    @api strRecordId;
    arrayFields = ['Name', 'AccountNumber', 'Phone', 'Type', 'Website'];
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Iliasin, its hard to say without understanding your component's composition (child, parent, siblings, etc, etc) additionally, there is plenty of documentation on line as well as trailheads on how to properly achieve this based on how you organize your components.

Comment: @glls there are 2 separate lwc.So no parent, child, etc. Just what i posted and for example simple lwc with h1 to display value.

Comment: how are those 2 components linked to each other? are they both sibling in a parent component, or completely separate?

Comment: @glls  they are on one flow screen, but  nothing more.

Comment: you might want to update your post with all this information in order to avoid an extended discussion. thanks

Comment: @glls added, but i dont know what it changed. Its not possible to pass user input on the same screen in flow.

Answer (score 0):

Worst-case scenario, you can use [lightning-message-service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service) to communicate between both components. The documentation should be sufficient for you to get started.

Comment: Looks good, but maybe there is something involving flow cause  both lwc on flow screen?